# Setting output width for CopyToClipboard

Tags: cdf-format, interoperability, clipboard

Suppose I have a long string and I copy it to the clipboard:

```
s = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345";
CopyToClipboard[s]
```

When I paste the clipboard contents into a text editor I get that string all on a single line.

But when I use

```
CopyToClipboard[{s}]
```

I get

```
{"12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678\
90123456789012345"}
```

How can I avoid the line splitting?  I see `Options` and `Streams` and `TotalWidth` in the documentation but I can't make heads or tails of any of it.

(You might wonder why I'm using `{s}` rather than just `s`:  That seems to be the only way I can get a CDF document to copy anything to the clipboard.)

Comment: `CopyToClipboard[ToString@{s}]`

Comment: Or `CopyToClipboard[InputForm@{s}]` it depends of what do you want for quotes...

Comment: `CopyToClipboard["{" <> s <> "}"]`

Comment: @unlikely.  Thank you!  `CopyToClipboard[ToString@{s}]` does the trick.  And `CopyToClipboard["{" <> s <> "}"]` does not produce any output to the clipboard in a CDF document. It seems (to me) that in a CDF document only lists can be copied to the clipboard.  That leaves the dangling curly brackets to deal with but that's a different question and not so critical for my needs.  If you write-up your first comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @unlikely.  Maybe I spoke too soon.  When I tried CopyToClipboard[ToString@{s}] I could have sworn it worked in a CDF document but now it doesn't.  (Maybe I was still in Mathematica rather than the CDF Player.)  Let do a bit more testing.  Sorry.  (CopyToClipboard just doesn't work the same in Mathematica and a CDF document.)  And by "doesn't work" I mean nothing in the clipboard rather than the split lines.

Comment: Sorry, I did'nt noticed the problem was arising in a CDF context. I think this may be related to low privileges / security reasons in a potentially low integrity application. What's your system and os?

Comment: In the 10.1.0 Front End this works: `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, {"PageWidth" -> 1000, "ExportTypesetOptions" -> {"PageWidth" -> 1000}}]`.  I have no idea how this relates to CDF.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard.  Using `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, {"ExportTypesetOptions" -> {"PageWidth" -> 1000}}]` does it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting a comment to an answer, in the 10.1.0 Front End this works:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
  {"PageWidth" -> 1000, "ExportTypesetOptions" -> {"PageWidth" -> 1000}}]
```

I do not use CDF so I do not know how this relates.

I found that I needed to set both options shown or the copy would still wrap.  The value 1000 was purely arbitrary; [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity.html) may suit your needs better.