# Extra character in StringJoin

Tags: string-manipulation

When I was trying to join a URL with a parameter and execute it with `URLFetch`, something unexpected happened.

Here is the code (The URL below doesn't exist and is just for illustration.)

Case 1 (Good):

`"http://www.google.com/analysis/key=" <> "12345"`

will give
`"http://www.google.com/analysis/key=12345"`

Case 2 (Weird):

`"http://www.google.com/analysis/key=" <> "12345678910111213141516171819202122"`

will give
`"http://www.google.com/analysis/key=\
12345678910111213141516171819202122"`

Note that the `\` is shown when copying it out. And I think that's the reason the URLFetch fails.

So how can I fix this?

Comment: You probably want: `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, "ExportTypesetOptions" -> {"PageWidth" -> Infinity}]`. This has been discussed in e.g. [Setting output width for CopyToClipboard](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108762/27951), of which this question is a likely duplicate.

Comment: Do this: highlight the link, right-click, and do copy-as... plain text.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylongstring = "12345678910111213141516171819202122";
 "http://www.google.com/analysis/key=" <> mylongstring
```

If your window is narrow, *Mathematica* will insert a new-line character.  Try opening your window nice and wide.  It worked for me.

Comment: In the Mathematica window it displays normally. However, an extra `\ ` is added to the string when copying it out to somewhere else.